# graph histogram using python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a sample data from 2014 through 2018 and need to plot a histogram to find outliers. But first, I need to figure out how many of the unique 162 IDs are in 2014, 2015...2018 and then plot it out. I first store data_2014 = data['DATE'].dt.year == 2014 for year 2014, but how do I find which of the 162 unique IDs occurred in 2014? Thank you so much!

```
|        ID     |    DATE      | VIOLATIONS |
| 0      CHI065 |  2014-07-08  |        65  |
| 1      CHI010 |  2014-07-16  |        56  |
| 2      CHI069 |  2014-07-08  |        10  |
| 3      CHI010 |  2014-07-26  |       101  |
| 4      CHI010 |  2014-07-27  |        92  |
| 5      CHI068 |  2014-08-03  |        20  |
| 17049  CHI040 |   2018-12-22 |        15  |
| 170496 CHI168 |  2018-12-23  |        16  |
| 170497 CHI103 |  2018-12-23  |         8  |
```

Comment: Thanks for revising the table for me.  I used control k today after I formatted the table via notebook just like I did yesterday, but instead of formatting it on stackoverflow, it kept going to google search bar on chrome.  Is there a faster way to format data on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '26-1-2014', 1: '26-1-2014', 2:'26-1-2015', 3:'30-1-2014'}, 
                  'ID': {0:"id12", 1: "id13", 2: "id14", 3: "id12"}, 'violations': {0: 34, 1:3, 2: 45, 3: 15} } )
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%Y')
```

Return unique Ids per year as dictionary or dataframe for easy lookup

```
d = df.groupby('year')['ID'].apply(set).to_dict() # as dictionary
d['2014'] #returns unique ids for 2014
```

The following line creates a df with unique IDs per year. This is good if you just want to know which ids are part of 2014.

```
df_ids = df.groupby('year')['ID'].apply(set).to_frame(name="id_per_year") #as dataframe
```

You can now subset on year for example to get only the rows from 2014

```
df = df.loc[df['year'] == '2014'] # subset for 2014
```

If you only want to count the unique IDs for 2014 you can groupby year and use [nunique()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html)

```
df_unique = df.groupby('year')['ID'].nunique().to_frame(name="unique_counts")
```

The following line creates a frame with counts of IDs per year

```
df_counts = df.groupby('year')['ID'].count().to_frame(name="count")
```

hope this helps

## EDIT 1: included aggregations to address comments

This will generate a table with the number count for each ID + its total number of violations for this year.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '26-1-2014', 1: '26-1-2014', 2:'26-1-2015', 3:'30-1-2014'}, 
                  'ID': {0:"id12", 1: "id13", 2: "id14", 3: "id12"}, 'violations': {0: 34, 1:3, 2: 45, 3: 15} } )
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%Y')

aggregations = {'ID': 'count', 'violations': 'sum'}

df_agg = df.groupby(['year', 'ID']).agg(aggregations)

corr = df_agg.groupby('year')[['ID', 'violations']].corr() #optional
```

If you like the number of unique IDs per year you can adjust the aggregations and the grouping

```
aggregations = {'ID': pd.Series.nunique, 'violations': 'sum'}
df_agg = df.groupby('year').agg(aggregations)
```

You can make a scatter plot like this. Make sure to add a color for each year in palette.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(df_agg["ID"], df_agg["violations"],hue=df_agg.index.get_level_values("year"),palette=["r", "b"], legend='full')
```

Comment: Yes, that helped, but I"m trying to create a final_variable for 2014 that will connect the number of citation and the number of cameras for year 2014 and I would do this for rest of the years.  
Thanks to you, I have 3 versions of data. first shows all subset of 2014, the second one shows all the active cams each year
and the third shows number of citations for year. note: the unique identifier between all three should be the year. 

I'm not sure if the final variable 2014 should use subset of 2014 and connect to citation variable df_cit_yr or should it connect to the variable df_unique.

Comment: first one: 
data_2014= df1.loc[df1['YEAR'] == '2014'] # all the records in 2014                                Second one:  df_unique = df1.groupby('YEAR')['ID'].nunique().to_frame(name="Number_of_active_cameras") # of cameras from 2014 - 2018                                                                                                                     Third one: 
df_cit_yr = df1.groupby(['YEAR'])['VIOLATIONS'].sum() # number of citations per year 
The end result is that I will have a final variable for each year that has citation and violation for that year.

Comment: in the end, I need to show
the graph via matplotlib that if there's any correlation between the number of cams installed and number of violation for that year.

Comment: I'm trying to connect citation and violations via year.  
fin_2014 = df_unique[df_cit_yr.YEAR == 2014]  # this gives an error saying objects has no attribute

Comment: make sure year is within quotes "2014". My edit 1, might provide a easier way to address your problem

Comment: Thank you, Mack! I was able to create scatter plots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-separately-from-pandas-datetime-column) to get the year in a new column

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DATE']).year
```

or

```
df['year'] = df['ArrivalDate'].dt.year
```

then use groupby and agg to get a count of each year:

```
counts = df.groupby('year').agg('count')
```

So each year

Comment: df_unique = df1.groupby('YEAR')['ID'].nunique().to_frame(name="Number_of_active_cameras") # of cameras from 2014 - 2018   I"m trying to plot the year in the x-axis and ID in Y-axis but plt.plot (df_unique.ID, df_unique.ID) is not working. It doesn't recognize ID and YEAR